# Jupyter Notebook AttributeError: SQL Database in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, algorithmic-trading

My problem is about how can I solve this AttributeError , here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlalchemy
from binance import Client
from binance import BinanceSocketManager

client = Client('api', 'secret_api')
bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
socket = bsm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT')

while True:
    await socket.__aenter__()
    msg = await socket.recv()
    frame = createframe(msg)
    frame.to_sql('BTCUSDT', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    print(frame)
```

But it raises the following Error to me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11340/3652326046.py in <module>
      3     msg = await socket.recv()
      4     frame = createframe(msg)
----> 5     frame.to_sql('BTCUSDT', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
      6     print(frame)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_sql'
```

Here is the "createframe" function:

```
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg])
    df = df.loc[:,['s','E','p']]
    df.columns = ['symbol','Time','Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms')
```

Comment: Looks like createframe returns null

Comment: Yeah, Any suggestions? I'll be very grateful to know!

Comment: Not familiar with createframe. Is it yours? Can you debug?

Comment: Can I use pd.DataFrame() instead?

Comment: Perhaps but what does the createframe documentation say? Do we have a link or something to that?

Comment: def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg])
    df = df.loc[:,['s','E','p']]
    df.columns = ['symbol','Time','Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms')

Comment: Here is the function .

Comment: Please edit your question to include `createframe`. From what I can quickly see the function does not return the `df`. Is it a function from a package you 've been using?

Comment: yup already done what you've said ! maybe you need to refresh the page

Comment: Good, and as I said `createframe()` does not have a return statement anywhere. Therefore `frame = createframe(msg)` assigns to `frame` value `None`. Then, `frame.to_sql(...)` throws an exception because `frame==None`. The exception is telling you exactly this: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_sql'`, because `None` your `frame`, does not have any functions to call!

Comment: So what can I do mr.life saver?

Comment: Stay calm and try to see if my answer works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `createframe` method, does not return anything. I would propose you to change it to something like:

```
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg])
    df = df.loc[:,['s','E','p']]
    df.columns = ['symbol','Time','Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='ms')
    return df # Here is the change where it returns your DataFrame to where it is called from
```

I hope this works. Can not really post more because we lack more background to your question